# Can`t seem to make the selector select right

Tags: javascript, html, selector

```
<div class="form_div">
<form name="first" class="dirs" method="post" action="">

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="path..." class="info">
    <div class="tip">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".info").tip({ effect : 'slide'});
});
</script>
```

I want to select the div with the class tip and img tag class info from the div > form > table > tr > td. But i can't select it with the function i have in the script.
The selector doesn't find the img tag and the div with the class tip.
Am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: what javascript librarys/plugins are you using other than jQuery `.tip({})` isnt a function i've heard of. What are you trying to apply ot the elements once youve selected your image/div

Comment: @ManseUK I`m trying to select the img tag first,and then when the mouse will be over the img tag the tip class will apear with the effect slide.                                                             @Simon West i`m using this http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(".info, .tip")
```

Its a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

And look at [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: i tried it and worked,thank you,also placed the script function on the top od the page. Thank you

Comment: @Nebunel You dont need to place the script at the top as you are using the `.ready()` method - this will only execute the code when the DOM has completed loading

Comment: Go figure... **the only incorrect answer got accepted** (and helped the guy in some odd way...).

Comment: I have tried to place again on the bottom of the page,or in the middle and it doesn`t select it,don`t know why,i`m reading now some more documentation about jquery and javascript, i want find out if the problem is because i have 4-5 elseif statements and in each elseif the same img tag and div with the same class.

Comment: Sorry ManseUK i rushed, i will explore the other answers and then post what was the good one. I apologize.

Comment: @Nebunel no need to apologise to me ... its `@gdoron` who was not impressed with your choice ...

Comment: the code is here http://codepad.org/QVYxi04A  if css needed i will post it. I modifyed it a bit to see if the selectors truly selects what i want

Comment: http://codepad.org/779AgJT8 fixed, but still the div after the img tag is not selected. Is it because of the td element?

Comment: @Nebunel I took one of your `div`s and it works here -> http://jsfiddle.net/eaAjU/

Comment: @ManseUK fixed it. the selector was getting the right item, only i was doing something wrong with the slideup(),slideDown(),if i put now $(".pont").Show() it displays the div, but on $(".pont").SlideUp() nothing. Don`t know what for sure but i am still reading,maybe i will know the cause. Thank you very much for responding and i`m sorry if i was a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your javascript code at the top of the body

Comment: doesnt make any difference - its within a `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: it worked! thank you. i am wondering,is because i place php code and multiple elseif that has the same classes that javascript didn`t know the first time to select? or i am mistaken? (I`m new to javascript/jquery)

Comment: @Nebunel. It just couldn't not be it!!! Your code is in the bottom already, and it's inside DOM ready handler. Are you sure?!

Comment: @gdoron If I place the script code on the bottom of the page it doesn`t select any of the classe, but if I place it on top it work for every elseif code of block that has the divs with the class and the img tag that i want to select. I want to know now why, i`m very curious

Comment: @Nebunel where do you add the library you are using ???? that needs to be above the `script` block ... thats about it (when using `.ready()`)!